# My bootstrap website takes forever to load videos, and sometimes puts random images in its place

Tags: performance, video, size, footer

I've been looking for a solution to these problems. Basically, I had never used bootstrap before (or CSS), and have bought a template online: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0NFRM26

I've managed to turn that into this: [www.votgaus.com](http://www.votgaus.com)

That's my website. I think I've done a pretty decent job knowing it's my first experience with CSS. So far, I've been able to find solutions online to everything but these two things:

1) My footer, when opened on my iPhone, expands and fills the whole screen but not the whole text is shown. It's kind of weird to explain. If you can actually open it on your iphone you'll see what I mean. The last line gets cut off at the end. And the only way you can actually close the footer and see the logo at the top is if you scroll down (which is fine). But you can't scroll to show the last line. Why?? This is some of the code. I really have no idea what i'm doing. I put the max-height inside footer, but don't understand then why do I have the .collapse-footer for. I'm really confused as to how this footer was made (I pulled it from bootsnipp).

```
footer {
  background:#764554;
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100vh;


}
footer .panel {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.collapse-footer {
  padding-bottom:0px
  z-index: 1;
    max-height: 100vh;

}
.collapse-footer p {
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:normal;

}
```

I think this stems from the fact that I don't really understand where to put the max-height attribute, maybe.

2) My videos take forever to load. Not videos in general, but the videos in the header of the sections. Each section has a banner and the background is either a video or a picture. I've made them quite light, up to a megabyte maximum and most only are 500 KB. At the beginning, I started putting my videos (not the ones from the template) on mp4 and each like 10MB. I thought that was the problem. The template actually has each video in three different versions (mp4, webm and ogg). I thought I could choose. So later I made them webm and reduced the size. It still is so slow. So I decided to get rid of the loader at the beginning since it was giving me so many problems, especially on phones. Nothing. I then changed the name of the folder to webm, and changed the html as well to pick it up. In theory, I should put a still frame on jpeg with the same name, so that on phones it just pulls the picture instead of the video. This is messing everything. Sometimes it loads the videos, sometimes pictures (both on phone and computer), sometimes it mixes the images, even from separate folders. And sometimes refreshing it makes it work much better, but it still takes SOO long compared to how fast the template is. Don't understand why. I've tried making a version of the html where it doesn't pull video and just goes for the still (by forcing the src to the .jpeg), but still, it will pull video sometimes, and load really slow.

I don't know which part of the code is relevant to this. My whole css stylesheet is here:

www.votgaus.com/css/main.css

HTML is just www.votgaus.com . Bootstrap is www.votgaus.com/css/bootstrap.min.css . SASS which I don't even know how it works is www.votgaus.com/sass/main.sass

Thank you to anyone who could give me a tip or help me fix this, even if it's just telling me what to look for. Especially with the loading so slow.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your own streaming server? If none maybe try hosting your video in some cloud hosting server, explains here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/using-amazon-cloudfront-for-video-streaming/

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention. Not videos in general, but the videos in the header of the sections. Each section has a banner and the background is either a video or a picture.

Comment: Yup, since your video was hosted into your server it might take time to load because they are all streaming all at once and probably affect your bandwidth distribution unlike hosting your video in some cloud server that support fast video streaming, it will load fast. 

How do you embed your video? have you tried using youtube to see the difference of loading time between your video and some video from youtube?

Comment: it won't let me do that. There's actually javascript I think that's what's making it work, I can't just put the link to youtube. I'm looking at the javascript, and though I know nothing, i can sort of tell that it is defining the path for the video, so I should store them in my server. Also, the template runs very smooth and it has the videos on the same folder as I do. www.votgaus.com/js/main.js , and www.votgaus.com/js/vendor/jquery.vide.js (there's a bunch more js files)